# Appending into fix-sized list

Tags: python, list, built-in

I'm looking for a simple way to appending into fix-sized list.

If the list has max value `n` and there is another item appended into this list, the first item of the `list` would be removed.

There is a way but I think it is not efficient and it's quite overkill. How should I do this?

```
class fix_sized_list():
    def __init__(self,_max):
        self.max = _max
        self._list = []

    def add(self,item):
        print len(self._list)
        if len(self._list)>=self.max:
            self._list.pop(0)
            self._list.append(item)
        else:
            self._list.append(item)


c = fix_sized_list(8)

for x in range(50):
    c.add(x)
    print c._list
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a list, use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) (which essentially works like a simple queue data strcuture). Provide it a [`maxlen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque.maxlen) argument to fix its size.

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> queue = deque(maxlen=2)
>>> queue.append(1)
>>> queue
deque([1], maxlen=2)
>>> queue.append(2)
>>> queue
deque([1, 2], maxlen=2)
>>> queue.append(3)
>>> queue
deque([2, 3], maxlen=2)
```